# For every $0<x<1$, is it possible to find a number $p>0$ such that $x=\frac{1}{1+p}$ or squeezed between two such fractions?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

It sounds like true. I am trying to find a rigorous proof. I will post it here if I can find one. Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: Can $p$ be any positive real number?

Comment: yes, $p$ can be any positive real number.

Comment: $$p=\frac1x-1\ldots$$

Comment: Answer is in my question. Just solve $x= \frac{1}{1+p}$  for $p$. LOL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One is always allowed to write, for $0<x<1$,
$$
x=\frac1{1+\left(\frac1x-1 \right)}
$$ of course $\frac1x-1>0$.

Comment: That was very clever. This solves my problem. Thanks a BUNCH !!!

Comment: @Mr. MBB You are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Fix $x \in (0,1)$.  Let $p = \dfrac{1-x}{x}$.  This satisfies $x = \dfrac{1}{1+p}$.  And this choice of $p$ is ok because $0 < x < 1$, i.e., $x \ne 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint (based on the original question, where "squeezed between fractions" suggested that $p$ must be an integer): The sequence $1/2, 1/3, 1/4, \ldots$ decreases monotonically to its limit $0$. What does the claim say about (for examples) $3/4$ and $1/\pi$?